# Jquery click doesn't work on append

Tags: jquery, onclick, click, append

I'm trying to use the JQuery .click on a div that i append, but the click doesn't work at all. here is the code, i already tried the help from the other Tutorials i could find on the internet but it didn't work.

here is the jquery (very simple version) :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$( "#DivResult" ).click(function() {

    alert('yolo');
 //$( "#return" ).submit();
});
});
```

And the way i create my DivResult with Ajax and append :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#monForm').on('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $this = $(this);
        var adrall = $('#villeDepart').val();
        var adrarr = $('#villeArrivee').val();
        var datedepart = $('#datedepart').val();
        var nombreplace = $('#nombreplace').val();
        $.getJSON('/app.php/rechT/refresh', {data: adrall + ' , ' + adrarr + ' , ' + datedepart + ' , ' + nombreplace}
        ).done(function (Res) {
            console.log(Res);
            $("#resultcontainer").html("");
            if (Res == "") {
                secondchoix();
                tiercechoix();
            }
            else {
                $.each(Res, function (ligne, result) {
                    var resultats =
                            "<div class=" + '"output container col-lg-8 blueskycont col-lg-offset-2"' + ' id="DivResult"'+ 
                            ">" + " <form name=" + '"retour"' + " action=" +
                            '"/app.php/validationdemande/go"' + "role=" + '"form"' + " method=" + '"POST"' + " class=" + '"retour"' + ' id="return"'+
                            "> <div class=" + '"form-group col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-xs-sm-12 col-xs-12"' + ">" +
                            "<label class=" + '"funzies col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-xs-sm-12 col-xs-12 move"' + " for=" + '"pwababd"' + ">" + result.TRAJ_LIEU_DEP + " -> " + result.TRAJ_LIEU_ARR + "</label>" +
                            " <label class=" + '"funzies col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-xs-sm-12 col-xs-12"' + "> Départ le : " + result.TRAJ_DATE + "</label> " +
                            " <label class=" + '"funzies col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-xs-sm-12 col-xs-12"' + "> De : " + result.PROT_LIEU_DEP + "</label> " + "</br>" +
                            " <label class=" + '"funzies col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-xs-sm-12 col-xs-12"' + "> " + result.PROT_LIEU_ARR + "</label> " + "</br>" +
                            " <label class=" + '"funzies col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-xs-sm-12 col-xs-12"' + "> A : " + result.TRAJ_NB_PLACE + " places restante(s) </label> " + "</br>" +
                            "<label class=" + '"funzies col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-xs-sm-2 col-xs-2"' + "> " + result.PROF_PRENOM + " " + result.PROF_NOM + " </label> " +
                            "<input type=" + '"HIDDEN" class="" id="" name="PROT_ID" value="' + result.PROT_ID + '">' +
                            "<input type=" + '"HIDDEN" class="" id="" name="PROT_RED" value="' + result.PROT_RED + '">' +
                            "<input type=" + '"HIDDEN" class="" id="" name="TRAJ_TYPE" value="' + result.TRAJ_TYPE + '">' +
                            "<input type=" + '"HIDDEN" class="" id="" name="VILLE_DEP" value="' + result.TRAJ_LIEU_DEP + '">' +
                            "<input type=" + '"HIDDEN" class="" id="" name="VILLE_ARR" value="' + result.TRAJ_LIEU_ARR + '">' +
                            "<input type=" + '"HIDDEN" class="" id="" name="LIEU_DEP" value="' + result.PROT_LIEU_DEP + '">' +
                            "<input type=" + '"HIDDEN" class="" id="" name="LIEU_ARR" value="' + result.PROT_LIEU_ARR + '">' +
                            "<input type=" + '"HIDDEN" class="" id="" name="nombreplace" value="' + nombreplace + '">' +
                            "<input type=" + '"HIDDEN" class="" id="" name="demande_ville_dep" value="' + adrall + '">' +
                            "<input type=" + '"HIDDEN" class="" id="" name="demande_ville_arr" value="' + adrarr + '">' +
                            "</div>  </form> </div>";

                    $("#resultcontainer").append(
                            resultats
                            );
                });
            }
        })
                .fail(function (Res) {
                    alert('fail');          
                })
                .error(function (Res) {
                    alert('erreur');
                });
    });
});
```

I'm trying to use it to submit since : `onClick="document.forms[\'retour\'].submit();"` 
doesn't work on IE.

But the clic does not respond at all on the DivResult. Does it mean i can't use a Jquery.click on a div that I append?

Comment: Actually, `.click()` simulate a click. Use `.on("click", function() { // Whatever you want });` or `.onMouseDown(function() { // Whatever you want });`, but I prefere the first one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need event delegation!

```
$("#resultcontainer").on("click", "#DivResult", function() {

});
```

Handlers are bound at runtime - and since your elements don't exist then, no handlers are bound. This will check `#resultcontainer` each click for the `#DivResult` and run the handler if found.

Comment: Thanks a lot i would never have find it out myself... it works very well, even on IE! Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the yolo part inside of the bottom of your big results function. My theory is that your DivResult doesn't exist yet when you are calling 'onclick':

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#monForm').on('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $this = $(this);
        var adrall = $('#villeDepart').val();
        var adrarr = $('#villeArrivee').val();
        var datedepart = $('#datedepart').val();
        var nombreplace = $('#nombreplace').val();
        $.getJSON('/app.php/rechT/refresh', {data: adrall + ' , ' + adrarr + ' , ' + datedepart + ' , ' + nombreplace}
        ).done(function (Res) {
            console.log(Res);
            $("#resultcontainer").html("");
            if (Res == "") {
                secondchoix();
                tiercechoix();
            }
            else {
                $.each(Res, function (ligne, result) {
                    var resultats =
                            "<div class=" + '"output container col-lg-8 blueskycont col-lg-offset-2"' + ' id="DivResult"'+ 
                            ">" + " <form name=" + '"retour"' + " action=" +
                            '"/app.php/validationdemande/go"' + "role=" + '"form"' + " method=" + '"POST"' + " class=" + '"retour"' + ' id="return"'+
                            "> <div class=" + '"form-group col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-xs-sm-12 col-xs-12"' + ">" +
                            "<label class=" + '"funzies col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-xs-sm-12 col-xs-12 move"' + " for=" + '"pwababd"' + ">" + result.TRAJ_LIEU_DEP + " -> " + result.TRAJ_LIEU_ARR + "</label>" +
                            " <label class=" + '"funzies col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-xs-sm-12 col-xs-12"' + "> Départ le : " + result.TRAJ_DATE + "</label> " +
                            " <label class=" + '"funzies col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-xs-sm-12 col-xs-12"' + "> De : " + result.PROT_LIEU_DEP + "</label> " + "</br>" +
                            " <label class=" + '"funzies col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-xs-sm-12 col-xs-12"' + "> " + result.PROT_LIEU_ARR + "</label> " + "</br>" +
                            " <label class=" + '"funzies col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-xs-sm-12 col-xs-12"' + "> A : " + result.TRAJ_NB_PLACE + " places restante(s) </label> " + "</br>" +
                            "<label class=" + '"funzies col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-xs-sm-2 col-xs-2"' + "> " + result.PROF_PRENOM + " " + result.PROF_NOM + " </label> " +
                            "<input type=" + '"HIDDEN" class="" id="" name="PROT_ID" value="' + result.PROT_ID + '">' +
                            "<input type=" + '"HIDDEN" class="" id="" name="PROT_RED" value="' + result.PROT_RED + '">' +
                            "<input type=" + '"HIDDEN" class="" id="" name="TRAJ_TYPE" value="' + result.TRAJ_TYPE + '">' +
                            "<input type=" + '"HIDDEN" class="" id="" name="VILLE_DEP" value="' + result.TRAJ_LIEU_DEP + '">' +
                            "<input type=" + '"HIDDEN" class="" id="" name="VILLE_ARR" value="' + result.TRAJ_LIEU_ARR + '">' +
                            "<input type=" + '"HIDDEN" class="" id="" name="LIEU_DEP" value="' + result.PROT_LIEU_DEP + '">' +
                            "<input type=" + '"HIDDEN" class="" id="" name="LIEU_ARR" value="' + result.PROT_LIEU_ARR + '">' +
                            "<input type=" + '"HIDDEN" class="" id="" name="nombreplace" value="' + nombreplace + '">' +
                            "<input type=" + '"HIDDEN" class="" id="" name="demande_ville_dep" value="' + adrall + '">' +
                            "<input type=" + '"HIDDEN" class="" id="" name="demande_ville_arr" value="' + adrarr + '">' +
                            "</div>  </form> </div>";

                    $("#resultcontainer").append(
                            resultats
                            );
                });
            }
        })
                .fail(function (Res) {
                    alert('fail');          
                })
                .error(function (Res) {
                    alert('erreur');
                });
    });

    $( "#DivResult" ).click(function() {
        alert('yolo');
 //$( "#return" ).submit();
    });
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure if i understood very well your point but i suppose it was existing since the other answer worked, by delegation of my event. I guess i wasn't using the good listener